# cloud build issue while deleting data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am using google cloud build to create an image using code and files. I can see the files on google cloud console and docker image in registry . I want to delete the source code from google server and only keep the docker registry.
How to delete the source code stored on google server? How securely the data is stored there?

Comment: Are you worried about Cloud Build downloading your source code in order to perform the build and then at the conclusion of the Cloud Build that the source code may "leak"?

Comment: Where are you seeing the source code in the console? On Source repository?

Comment: @Kolban, Yes I am afraid that source code may leak, it is physically on some server which I don't know . and it will be a shared server

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, when I go to cloud build console, I can see the past build logs and details, there is a source code download option which has .tz file. Once downloaded and open i can see everything.

Comment: @Kolban My cloud build is not linked to any version control system. I am triggering cloud build from my computer. first step google does is to zip the code and transfer it to server and then docker build.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your source code is stored to a version control system, Google Cloud Build integrates with GitHub or Google Cloud Repository which can directly download the code from the repo.

Or you can setup a trigger to automatically trigger a build on code push.

Unless you have a specific reason to download source code to Google Cloud Console I don't think you need to. That said, except you, noone else has access to Google Cloud Console. And Google Cloud Console deletes your data after certain amount of days if you haven't logged in.

Hope this helps.